# Person- vs. grand-mean centering in Mixed Effects Model

Tags: mixed-model, modeling, centering

I have a data set containing data of roughly 300 individuals with for each individual at most 3 observations. I want to make a simple mixed effects model of the form

```
lmer(response ~ predictor1 + (1 + predictor1 | individual))
```

However, I am unsure about whether to use person mean centering or grand mean centering for predictor1 and I am getting lost in the available literature.

A couple of questions come to mind:

1) What would be the practical difference between the two types of centering and how to interpret the results?

2) Are 3 observations per individual enough to even consider person mean centering?

3) One of my main questions is: "if an individual scores higher on predictor1 than he would on average, does that imply a higher response?". Would a certain type of centering help me answer this question?

4) Would person mean centering give me more information on personal differences than grand mean centering would?

5) What would be best practice here?